# How to return array of int in double pointer?

Tags: c

I need to write a function that returns an array of arrays:

```
return_array = { {1}, {1,2,3}, {...}, ....};
```

Each array has a different size. The function must comply to following signature:

```
int** generate(int n, int** column_sizes)
```

`n` is the input to function and I use that to create the `return-array`.
I know how to create `return_array`, but I don't understand how size of each array should be returned in double pointer `int** column_sizes`?

I would just returned them in a single pointer `int* column_sizes` like below:

```
int** generate(int n, int* column_sizes){
    int return_size=some_function(n); 
    int** returned_array=malloc(return_size*sizeof(int*));
    ...
    column_sizes[0]=c0; // First array size
    column_sizes[1]=c1; // Second array size
    ...
    return returned_array;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works with a single pointer. Where is the function declaration from?

Comment: @Osiris It's something given. I can't change it.

Comment: Other question, how do you know how many columns you created?

Comment: I assume it is supposed to be a double pointer so you can allocate an array to put the column sizes into (*) and then pass it to the caller by a pointer (second *)

Comment: @Pelipap Thats a very good point, since the number of arrays is obtained inside the function.

Comment: It would help to see the code that calls your function.

Comment: @Pelipap Hmm why they would want to do that? It's a credible source so they should have a good reason for it.

Comment: Because this function has to return two pieces of information: One the array containing the actual information and another array that describes how the returned array is _split up_ into sub-arrays. Such a seond return value is often realized using a pointer in C.

Comment: @Learner As said if you determine the number of arrays inside the function it would make sense to allocate it then. Otherwise it needs to be "big enough for every case".

Comment: "How to return array of int in pointer to pointer?" --> detail: In C _arrays_ cannot be returned.  Pointers can be returned, not arrays.

Comment: `int**` is not an array, it is not a 2D array, it is not a pointer to an array and it is not a pointer to a 2D array. Thus the function signature doesn't make any sense. It seems likely that you are another victim to bad teachers/books - see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `column_sizes` parameter is to pass the number of elements in each of the sub-arrays of the returned double-pointer to the caller.

If it is to be allocated inside your function, it has to be a double pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int** generate(int n, int** column_sizes){


    *column_sizes = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        (*column_sizes)[i]=i;

    int** return_array=malloc(n*sizeof(*int));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        return_array[i]=malloc((*column_sizes)[i]*sizeof(int));
        for(int j=0; j<(*column_sizes)[i]; j++) {
            // set the j'th value in the i'th array
            return_array[i][j]=i*j;
        }
    }
    return return_array;
}

int main() {
    int *column_sizes;

    int n=4;

    int** arrays= generate(n, &column_sizes);
    printf("%i\n", *column_sizes);


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<column_sizes[i]; j++) {
            printf("%i %i: %i\n",i,j, arrays[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int** return_array=malloc(t*sizeof(int));` allocates space for `t` `int`, but `return_array` points to `int *`. Additionally, the fact the return type is `int **` rather than `int *` suggests what should be returned is not a pointer to one pointer to some `int` but rather a pointer to multiple pointers to `int`, one for each “column”. In fact, the code shown to fill the arrays conforms to that, since it uses `return_array[i][j]`, but no code is shown to allocate space for those pointers or to assign values to them.

Comment: Hm that's a good point. your interpretation fits better, I updated my answer

Comment: I don't think this is all correct. It must be `*(column_sizes)[0]=1;` missing parenthesis in your code.

Comment: Yep, I thought * had precendence over [ ] and I was wrong. Tested and there's a working example now.

Answer (score 1):

There are some unresolved issues in the question, notably:

- How are the column sizes determined?
- How will the caller free the allocated memory?

Nonetheless, we can start answering. It looks like you need to allocate at least **three** spaces: One for the column sizes, one for the pointers to the columns, and one for all the actual `int` data. This supposes we put all the `int` data for all the columns in a single array but point into appropriate places in the array through the column pointers. An alternative is to allocate space for each column’s data separately.

In the former case, the function could be:

```
int **generate(int n, int **column_sizes)
{
    // Allocate space for columns sizes and assign column sizes.
    int NumberOfColumns = /* Some calculation not explained in question. */;
        // (size_t would be better than int, but I will use the types in the question.)
    int *sizes = malloc(NumberOfColumns * sizeof *sizes);
    // Insert code to abort if malloc failed.
    *column_sizes = sizes;
    int TotalElements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; ++i)
    {
        sizes[i] = /* Some calculation to find size of column i. */;
        TotalElements += sizes[i];
    }

    // Allocate space for pointers to columns.
    int **returned_array = malloc(NumberOfColumns * sizeof *returned_array);
    // Insert code to abort if malloc failed.

    // Allocate space for the actual int data.
    int *Space = malloc(TotalElements * sizeof *Space);
    // Insert code to abort if malloc failed.

    // Assign pointers to columns.
    returned_array[0] = Space;
    for (int i = 1; i < NumberOfColumns; ++i)
        returned_array[i] = returned_array[i-1] + sizes[i-1];

    // Fill in the actual int data.
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < column_sizes[i]; ++j)
            returned_array[i][j] = /* Some unexplained calculation. */;

    return returned_array;
}
```

With this definition, the caller could free the memory by freeing the array of column sizes, freeing the space pointed to by the first pointer in the returned array, and freeing the returned array. If, in an alternative implementation, each column is allocated separately, the caller would have to free each pointer in the returned array.

Comment: I don't understand where you've allocated memory, you've used `sizeof *sizes` and `sizeof *returned_array` and `sizeof *Space`. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Learner: `sizeof expression` is the size of the type of the expression. If `x` is a pointer to `int`, then `sizeof *x` is the size of an `int`. Using `x = malloc(n * sizeof *x);` is preferred over `x = malloc(n * sizeof *x);` because, when you later edit the code to change what `x` is declared as, the sizes automatically remain correct; you do not have to go change all the types in `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: Would that be allowed? Because `sizeof ` is referring to a variable that has been just defined in the same line: `type* x = malloc(sizeof *x);`

Comment: @Learner: At the `=`, the type of `x` is complete (there is sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type, per C 2018 6.2.5 1), and so is the type of `*x`. So at that point or after, `sizeof` may be applied to `*x`.